# Inserting variable into layer name in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to insert current date into name of new layer.
My current code to save layer with hardcoded name is like this:

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,r"D:\Maps\layer.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

I can get current date using:

```
cur_date_apndx = time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
```

statement, but I can not insert cur_date_apndx into the code above. I think "r" in the 2nd parameter of `writeAsVectorFormat` is the reason. If I remove "r" layer is not saved.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer just using forward slashes instead of using raw string coupled with backward slashes. But you could use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) method to insert the date into the filename:

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "D:/Maps/layer_{}.shp".format(cur_date_apndx),"utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: 12 seconds between the two answers :)

Comment: @mgri - Indeed! And `cur_date_apndx` does come out as a string :)

Comment: @Joseph, perfect! But _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "D:/Maps/layer_{}.shp".format(cur_date_apndx),"utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile") doesn`t work and _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, r"D:/Maps/layer_{}.shp".format(cur_date_apndx),"utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile") is working.

Comment: @EBobrov - Most welcome although mgri's answer is also correct (and he answered first) so perhaps accept his answer as both our solutions are essentially the same? ;)

Comment: @Joseph - I do not know why but mgri`s answer (without r) is not working. Previously I tried hardcoded layer name without variable and r  method but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it right now, but if `cur_date_apndx` is a string, you may simply compose the output name in this way:

```
output_name = 'D:/Maps/layer_' + cur_date_apndx + '.shp'
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,output_name,"utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

otherwise, use `str(cur_date_apndx)` isntead of `cur_date_apndx`.

I used slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`) because your format time was `"%d_%m_%Y"` (but the method with `r` should however work).

Comment: Thank you! It is strange but statement without 'r' doesn`t work. I`ve commented it above.

Comment: @EBobrov weird behavior, maybe I'm missing something. Did you try using double quotes?

Comment: yap, I tried to use double quotes.